# prevent windows from opening (windowless application)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to make a windowless application. The problem is that I'm using a framework that shows some alert boxes sometimes, and I'm not able to suppress them (at least not without a crash).

I've set `LSBackgroundOnly` to 1 (in the info.plist app file), but this doesn't seem to work. Any chance I'm missing something here (maybe some other settings that I need to set)?

I've also tried creating a category for `NSWindow`:

1. Overwritten `alloc` and `allocWithZone:` so that no window gets created. This works on some situations, but starting a modal session throws exception (because sending a nil parameter to `beginModalSessionForWindow:`).
2. Tried overwriting NSApplication's `beginModalSessionForWindow:` and returned nil everytime, but this leads to EXC_BADACCESS somewhere in the framework (`runModalSession:` and `endModalSession:` were also overwritten, but the crash is before any of them being called).

Any other ideas will be welcome.

In case it helps, the framework that I'm using is Twain.Framework, so if instead anyone knows a way to block all UI from twain (this includes error alerts shown when a device is not connected) it would be great if you share.

Comment: I am new to iPhone development. & was reading the 'Views Prog Guide'. Apple says in doc that 'each app will have at least one window'. So how to make windowless app.? Pls clear my basics.. plsss....

Comment: @hpiOSCoder Sorry about the confusion, added the osx tag. The application is built for Mac.

Comment: okk. I was really wondered & curious too about implementing such an idea. thanks for update

Comment: @hpiOSCoder It makes no sense to make a windowless app on iOS. It will have no use and you won't even be allowed in the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it 'windowless' (some windows are still shown, but at least they're not visible, and they're automatically closed). I only handled modal windows, since these where shown in my situation.

1. I made a category for `NSWindow`, so that all windows are invisible, and can't become key or main windows:

   ```
   -(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow{
      [self setOpaque:NO];
      self.alphaValue = 0;
      return NO;
   }
   -(BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow{
      [self setOpaque:NO];
      self.alphaValue = 0;
      return NO;
   }
   ```
2. Subclassed `NSApplication`:

   ```
   -(NSInteger)runModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow{
      return NSCancelButton;
   }
   -(NSModalSession)beginModalSessionForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow{
      NSModalSession session = [super beginModalSessionForWindow:aWindow];
      [aWindow performSelector:@selector(close) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
      return session;
   }
   ```

However, this didn't help much. In case of `runModalForWindow:` everything was good, since the owner of the window received a response. In case of `beginModalSessionForWindow:` the application got stuck, most probably because the window's owner was waiting for a specific event (e.g. button click) which it never received.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're hoping for.  Are you hoping for an app that doesn't normally display windows but does allow the third-party framework to show its alerts?  Or are you hoping to find a way to prevent the framework from showing its alerts so your app absolutely **never** has any windows?

If it's the former, you're probably looking for LSUIElement.  That's an app which can have some UI elements, but doesn't show in the Dock or the Command-Tab application switcher and doesn't have a menu bar.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want the application to not show any UI at all.